# did he (deliberateky) say something

Tags: meaning, interrogatives

a. Did he say something for John to get angry?

b. Did he say something in order for John to get angry?

c. Did he say something you to get John angry?

d. Did he say something you in order to get John angry?

Which of the above imply that there is intention involved?

Which are asking whether he intentionally said something to get John angry?

Comment: Sorry; all of those are simply wrong. None is asking whether he intentionally said something to get John angry; none…

Can you find a better translator, or some better examples or both?

When you do, please remember that in this Question and this exposition it does not at all matter whether what he said was deliberate.

Answer (score 3):

First a correction. (c) and (d) should both say "Did he say something **to you**". You in that sentence is the *indirect* object, not the *direct* object.

Now to the main question.

**a. Did he say something for John to get angry?** This suggests that because John got angry there must have been a reason, and the question asks "was it because of something he said?" It is not necessary to read intention into this example.

**b. Did he say something in order for John to get angry?** This is ambiguous. We could read it exactly the same way as (a), but "in order" can suggest intention. See the notes on the next two examples.

**c. Did he say something (to) you to get John angry?** "To" is more likely to suggest intention than "for". This is because John is now the object of the clause. "I am getting angry" is a neutral statement about my feelings. "You are getting me angry" adds an extra dimension. Not only do we know about my feelings, we also know what has caused them.

However, "to get" doesn't necessarily mean intention. "You are getting me angry" means that I think you are the cause of my anger. But that still might not be what you intended. Maybe you weren't even aware that your actions were making me angry.

So this is ambiguous. "To get John angry" can mean "in order to get John angry", in which case it's an abbreviated form of example (d) and implies intention. Or it can mean "with the result that John got angry", in which case no intention is implied.

**d. Did he say something (to) you in order to get John angry?** This is the clearest example of intention. "In order to" means "for the purpose of". "I looked at the timetable in order to know when the train was coming." (My intention in looking at the timetable was to know when...)

Comment: It's an interesting area of potential ambiguity. I'm intrigued by the fact that simply switching what was said from ***something*** (unknown utterance) to ***that*** (*known* utterance) massively affects the implication of deliberate action. Hence *Did you say **something** to upset him?* (probably / possibly ***to = that*** - *unintentionally*), and *Did you say **that** to upset him?* (almost certainly ***to = in order to*** -  *intentionally*).